# Evaluating $ \lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{x^2-1}\,\exp(\frac1{x^2-1})$. Isn't this $\infty\times\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

I need to find the following limit,
$$
\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{x^2-1}\,\exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)
$$

**My attempt:** I think the form is $\infty\times\infty$ form and hence limit goes to $\infty$, but Wolfram says I am wrong. Please help.

Comment: Remember that as $x$ approaches $1$ *from below*, the exponent is negative so the exponential term goes to $0$ and you have a limit in the form of $0 \cdot \infty$.

Comment: @RobertShore sir, but there is $x^2$ which is always positive and hence how exponential term goes to $0$? Isn't it tends to $∞$

Comment: Sure, $x^2$ is positive, but what about $x^2-1$?

Comment: If $x=0.99$, what's the exponential term going to be?  How about if $x=0.99999$?

Comment: @runway44 sir, $x^2-1$ is also positive   except when $x\in (-1,1)

Comment: Yes, And when $x$ approaches $1$ from below, it is in the interval $(-1,1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
L=\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac1{x^2-1}\,\exp\left(\frac1{x^2-1}\right)
$$
$$\implies L=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{(1-h)^2-1}\exp\left( \frac{1}{(1-h)^2-1}\right)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-1}{2h}e^{-1/(2h)}$$
We have ignored $h^2$ in cparision ro $h$. It amounts to using binomial approcimation that $(1-z)^k \approx 1-kz, if |z|<<1.$
$$L=\lim_{t \to \infty} -te^{-t}= -\lim_{t\to \infty}\frac{t}{e^t}=0$$
By L'hospital.

Comment: Sir, how $h^2$ can be ignored?

Comment: Sir please reply

Comment: $h$ is alway <<1. It is as mall as we want. if $h=.01 \implies h^2=.0001$ which is much smaller. See the answer again I have added something.